# Is Astral Projection allowed in Judiasm and Halachah?

Tags: halacha, travel, sleep

I'm currently studying the subject and am interested in trying it out

basically when you go to sleep your soul departs however it happens unconscionably without you being aware of it happening

Astral Projection is when you consciously make it happen, you can travel the globe, check on distant relatives, visit deceased relatives, explore the universe and go back in time as an observer, when it's time to wake up in the morning you're automatically yanked back into your body

is there anything against it in Judaism and Halachah?

Comment: Judaism forbids imitating the irrational spiritual customs of gentiles.

Answer (score 2):

In [Pirkei D'Rebbe Eliezer (34)](http://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_DeRabbi_Eliezer.34.1?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) we find

> ר' זכריה אומ' שינת הלילה דומה לעולם למתים וישן ורוחות משוטטות בכל הארץ ומגדת לו בחלום כל דבר שיהיה שנ' בחלום בחזיון לילה אז נגלה אזן אנשים ובמוסרם יחתום כך המתים רוחות משוטטות בכל הארץ ומגדת להם כל דבר שהיה

This is saying that when a person sleeps his soul/spirit travels around the world and sees things and comes back to tell him in the form of a dream.
 IF this is what is happening on its own, there is no reason it should be prohibited to induce it.

The [Gemara in Sanhedrin (101a)](http://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.101a.44?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) allows paranormal behavior for informational purposes.
Ov and Yidoni is a separate issue, as [explained by the Maharal](http://www.sefaria.org/Be'er_HaGolah,_Well_2.15?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all). The Rambam, in his introduction to Mishnayos, discusses the difference between prophecy and clairvoyance. The Rambam famously mocked the idea of magic and explained that the idea of it being prohibited is to keep us away from foolishness. However, we see that he does give credence to natural clairvoyance and refers to it as a spiritual power.

Answer (score 1):

Astral projection is included in the category of spiritual practices of the nations. It is forbidden for a Jew to be involved with these practices as is found in the Semag, Mitzvot Lo Ta'aseh. In particular, visiting/consulting with the dead is included in the prohibition against the practice of 'yidoni'.

If you are personally interested in these more esoteric spiritual practices, you should seek out a qualified Orthodox Rabbi who has proper training in these areas and investigate them according to Jewish tradition.

You might consider checking out Rabbi Ariel Bar Tzadok at koshertorah.org.

http://www.koshertorah.com/

Comment: `Astral projection is included in the category of spiritual practices of the nations.` Source?